# Angular 2: Token based authentication

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to enter my authentication token in the headers of my requests but for some reason it keeps showing as undefined.

Service:

```
export class ClientService {

  token:string

    constructor (private http: Http, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public storage: Storage ) {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {

      this.storage.get("auth_token").then((val) => {

        // This prints the correct value
        console.log("show token", val) 
        this.token = val
      })
    })

getClients(page):Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers();

    // This prints undefined
    console.log("fetching clients", this.token);

    headers.append("authentication", this.token );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?page=${page}`, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
}
```

Comment: where's getClients being called? could it be happening before the promise for storage.get resolves?

Comment: I think that is the problem... I found a workaround where I provide the `token` as a parameter in the call to `getClients`